# Newline appears after when converting shapefile to spatialite

Tags: qgis-2, spatialite

I converted a layer from a shapefile format to spatialite. A line is added in the spatialite layer but record is not created in the attribute table (similar to multipart geometry). Shapefile to spatialite conversion was done just by right clicking the shapefile layer -> Save As spatialite.

[image]

The snapshot of the shapefile as well as spatialite layer is attached below.

[image]

I am curious to know what would be the reason?

Comment: Which SRS are you using? What is the source of the shapefile?

Comment: Source of the shapefile is EPSG:4326 WGS 84. FYI only one layer has this problem, the any other layer which I had converted doesn't have though.

Comment: As in "source", I meant "where did you get it"?

Comment: It was downloaded from census website. The region is United states.